# Prevent Quote Detail editing but allow the revision of the Quote itself

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

All users but a specific one should not be allowed to edit or update Quote Details which not satisfy a specific condition, but they have to be capable of revising the Quote if they want to.

The issue is, revising the Quote (i.e. the user clicks the "Revise" button in an Active form record) triggers the Update of the Quote Details and I can't figure out how to recognize what's going on.

My current attempt is based on a plugin which code looks like this:

```
public class PreQuoteProductUpdate : Plugin
{
// I work with CRM Developer Tools to build plugins 
// This goes in Update Message, Pre-Operation, Server Only, pre-image called "preImage"

protected void ExecutePreQuoteProductUpdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
    if (localContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
    }

    IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
    IOrganizationService srv = localContext.OrganizationService;

    Entity preImageEntity = (context.PreEntityImages != null && context.PreEntityImages.Contains(this.preImageAlias)) ? context.PreEntityImages[this.preImageAlias] : null;

    try
    {
        PluginBody(context, srv, preImageEntity);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Quote Details Pre-Update", ex);
    }
}

protected void PluginBody(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService srv, Entity preImage)
{
    if(IsRevising()) return;

    CheckSomeCondition(context, srv);

    if (preImage.Attributes.ContainsKey("ica_daconfigurazione") && preImage.GetAttributeValue<bool>("ica_daconfigurazione"))
    {
        CheckUser(context, srv);
    }
}

protected void IsRevising()
{
    // I have no clue about the logic to put here: see below.
}

protected void CheckSomeCondition(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService srv)
{
    var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
    // if some fields of entity contain some specific data, throw
    // this always happens
}

protected void CheckUser(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService srv)
{
    //allowedUser is read from a configuration entity
    var allowedUser = new Guid();
    if (context.InitiatingUserId.Equals(serviceUser.Id) == false)
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Can't edit quote details");
}
```

}

I know that (in a `Quote` plugin) I can know a revision is ongoing by checking the `ParentContext`, is anything similar available in a `QuoteDetail` plugin ? I gave it a try but all I get are `NullReferenceException`s thrown at me.

Should I expect to have `State`/`Status` available to check ?

For any more info which I may have overlooked, just ask.

Comment: What do you mean by revising? Do you mean if the user has just created the Quote and they make some edits immediately after creating it?

Comment: I mean the "Revise" standard feature (editing to clarify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register on the `Pre Create` message (stage 20) of `QuoteDetail` and filter on the parent context not being for `Quote`. If it is, just return (effectively doing nothing).
The same applies to the `Update` message of the `QuoteDetail`.
Both messages run in the context of the `ReviseQuote` message for `Quote`.

```
var parentContext = context.ParentContext;

// While there is a parent context...
while (parentContext != null) {
    // When parent context is for "quote", return;
    if (parentContext.PrimaryEntityName == "quote")
    {
        return;
    }
    // Assign parent's parent context to loop parent context.
    parentContext = parentContext.ParentContext;
}
```